# How one would typically detect systems vulnerable to “NULL Session”?

Tags: attacks

I got the question "Explain how one would typically detect systems vulnerable to “NULL Session” " ,but I do not know how to answer this question. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you already familiar with what a NULL-session is? The definition might vary on context. Is there a special context for this question?

Comment: @Philipp I'm pretty sure he's talking about accessing IPC$

Comment: Yes, that is IPC

Answer (score 1):

As @Philipp noted, it's not exactly clear, but if you are talking about a windows authentication null session, there are a lot of resources out there. Basically, it means you get access to some system resources shared on the network without needing real credentials to authenticate (log on). This [existing definition is pretty good](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Anatomy-Nul-Attack.html):

A remote session is created when a user logs on to a computer remotely using a username and password that has access to system resources. This is accomplished through the Server Message Block (SMB) protocol and the Windows Server service. These connections are entirely legitimate when proper credentials are supplied.

> A null session comes into play when a user makes a connection to a
>   windows system with no username or password. This type of connection
>   can not be made to any typical windows share, but it can be done to
>   the Interprocess Communication (IPC) administrative share. The IPC
>   share, as the name alludes to, is used by Windows processes (via the
>   SYSTEM username) to communicate with other processes across the
>   network. The IPC share is used exclusively by the SMB protocol.
>
> Using the IPC share with no credentials is typically reserved for
>   programs communicating with one another, but there is nothing to say
>   that a user could not connect to a machine via the IPC connection
>   instead. This would not allow for unrestricted access to the machine,
>   but will allow for pretty extensive enumeration that could aide an
>   attacker.

This site also explains how to test for this using `net use` command. There are also some purpose built tools for this you can find.